# VBScript to copy file/s beginning with XXX or YYY or ZZZ from directory A to directory B

Tags: vbscript, directory, copy, filenames

I have next to zero knowledge on vbs scripting but I have managed to cobble a few together to copy files from one directory to another and delete files in a directory but I've not been able to find anything specifically what I'm now after.

I'm looking to write a vbs script to do the following - copy file/s beginning with XXX or YYY or ZZZ from directory A to directory B.

I've had a look around and cannot quite find what I'm looking for, they all seem far too complex for what I need and involve the latest date or parsing a string within the files etc.

I'm quite sure this is simple but as stated at the top I really do not know what I'm doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is what I have for copying all files from one directory to another with a progress bar so a amendment to this would be great.

```
Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&

' copy test 1 to test 2
strTargetFolder = "C:\test2\" 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strTargetFolder) 
objFolder.CopyHere "C:\test1\*.*", FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as of yet how to get this in one big progress indicator. Currently it will show progress for each individual file.

```
Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H0&

strSourceFolder = "C:\test1\"
strTargetFolder = "C:\test2\" 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSourceFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)
Set objFiles = objSourceFolder.Files

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objTargetFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strTargetFolder)

For Each objSingleFile in objFiles
    If (InStr(1,objSingleFile.Name,"xxx",vbTextCompare) = 1) Or _
            (InStr(1,objSingleFile.Name,"yyy",vbTextCompare) = 1) Or _
            (InStr(1,objSingleFile.Name,"zzz",vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
        ' The file name starts with one the flagged keywords
        objTargetFolder.CopyHere objSingleFile.Path, FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
    End If
Next
```

Keep your `strTargetFolder` code which is used for the actual copy procedure used at the end of the script. Using the `FileSystemObject` `objFSO` we cycle through all the files of the directory `c:\test1`. Each file name is then checked to see if it starts with either of 3 different strings. The comparison is done using `vbTextCompare` which essentially has it running case insensitive. If a match is found then, using your original code, copy the file to the target directory with progress.

Currently this is not going to recursively navigate all subfolders for file but you could make a recursive function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FileSystemObject` in combination with a regular expression:

```
src = "C:\test1"
dst = "C:\test2" 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(XXX|YYY|ZZZ)"

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(src).Files
  If re.Test(f.Name) Then f.Copy dst & "\"
Next
```